# sticky table header cell when scrolling down the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please take a look at this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/89/)**. I'm trying to make the table header to stay on top when scrolling down the page. It isn't working as I expected because when the header becomes sticky, it changes the CSS style, making them off their respective columns. I've tried adding back the padding to `#sticky.stick > th` but nothing changed. Any suggestion?

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
}

$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<table id="comparetable" class="blueshine">
<tr id="sticky">
<td class="blank"> </td>                                      
<th>A</th>                                       
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
<th>D</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="rowTitle">Price</td>                                                                         <td>$4.5</td>
<td>$3.5</td>                                                   
<td>$2.5</td>
<td>$1.5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="rowTitle">Discount</td>                                                                       <td>50</td>                                                   
<td>60</td>                                              
<td>40</td>
<td>30</td> 
</tr>                                      
<tr>
<td class="rowTitle">Location</td>   
<td>Asia</td>                                                    
<td>Africa</td> 
<td>Europe</td> 
<td>Africa</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="rowTitle">Location</td>   
<td>Asia</td>                                                    
<td>Africa</td> 
<td>Europe</td> 
<td>Africa</td> 
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
/* START COMPARISON TABLE STYLES */
#comparetable {width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; text-align: center; margin: 4em 0; border-collapse: collapse; }
#comparetable tr {background: transparent!important;}
#comparetable td,
#comparetable th {padding: 20px; text-align: center;}
#comparetable td.rowTitle {text-align: left;}
.blank {background: none!important; border: none!important;}
 .blueshine th {background-color: #b8cee2; font-size: 22px; color: #0c3053; text-align: center; font-weight: 600; text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #e0ecf7; border: 1px solid #9fb6c8;}
 .blueshine td {background-color: #f0f1f1; border: 1px solid #c8d6e2;} 
 .blueshine td.rowTitle {border-left: 4px solid #333}
/* END COMPARISON TABLE STYLES */

#sticky {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 2em;
}
#sticky.stick {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
}
#sticky.stick > th {
padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: check out this plugin [Fixedheadertable](http://fixedheadertable.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes in your CSS:

```
.sticky {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 2em;
    display:none;
}
.sticky.stick {
    position:fixed;
    display:inline;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
.sticky #comparetable { margin:0; }
```

This is the HTML, basically you have to create a new table with just the header right after the #sticky-anchor and then put your table after this one.

```
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div class="sticky">
<table id="comparetable" class="blueshine">
<tr>
<td class="blank">&nbsp;</td>                                      
<th>A</th>                                       
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
<th>D</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<!-- your table goes here -->
<table id="comparetable" class="blueshine">
<tr> <!-- note that the id sticky has been removed -->
<td class="blank">&nbsp;</td>                                      
<th>A</th>                                       
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
<th>D</th>
</tr>
<tr>...
```

And change javascript to use class and not id:

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('.sticky').addClass('stick');
    } else {
        $('.sticky').removeClass('stick');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)